# change taborder order for two links on the page (from left to right)

Tags: html, css, accessibility, css-float, tabindex

Is there a way to change the tabindex order for two elements on the page without rewriting the html?

The part of the html page (the code is below):

```
<div>
<a href="#">one</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="right">
    <a href="#">two</a>  
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <a href="#">three</a>  
  </div>
</div>


<div>
<a href="#">four</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  border:1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.right {
  float:right;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

With the keyboard, using the Tab key, it jumps as one, two, three, four. However, the preferable order is one, three, two, four because of the left to right, top to bottom preference.

http://jsfiddle.net/bm93j18f/2/

Is here a way to fix it without significant rewriting the html code?

**Some more details:**
swapping the column order (and fixing css, right?) is the last resort, as the project is rather huge if there is no other option, the containers are not that simple and the problem is not for just one page.

Q.: Can we add to the HTML?

A.: something very simple (like adding tabindexes) would be the easiest and nice way.

Q.: Can we use JavaScript to manage focus order?

A.: No, if other options are possible.

Comment: Could you give a few more details about what restrictions you face. It is difficult to know what is a "significant rewrite" as I would just suggest swapping the column order (which is a minor rewrite to me ) so it makes sense but I am guessing you can't do that for some reason? Can we add to the HTML? Can we use JavaScript to manage focus order? Obviously the answer is swap the columns due to maintainability, simplicity, ease etc. so just wanted to know what we can and can't do here so we can offer a solution!

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I added more details to my question. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks that is useful, with regards to the contents I presume that the columns contents are **very varied** across different pages? With regards to the complexities of swapping the column orders (as **it is the answer** if we can possibly find some way to help you do that) are these static pages? The last resort would be JavaScript, grab the right column and move it after the left column but if we can come up with a one time backend solution that would be 100 times better. `tabindex` is a big no no as you would have to set the `tabindex` of every focusable item on each page.

Comment: For clarity I am approaching this from "Can we create a one time script to swap the column orders on the backend so everything is correct" followed by "Can we find a pattern and manage focus manually for certain columns" as a secondary option least likely to cause issues followed by "can we just grab the columns and swap their DOM order with JavaScript" as a last resort! from a robustness, maintenance and performance perspective I do worry about options 2 and 3.